# PDO: Dynamically detect database drivers

Tags: php, pdo

I'm creating my own CMS, part of this is making sure it is interoperable with different database types. PDO is therefore my default choice, my question is:

Is there any way to dynamically detect and set the database type in a PDO connection class?

As far as i can see there isn't so i was thinking just doing a bunch of try/catch on different database types then writing the one that doesn't throw an exception to a config file.

Comment: I think this is not a good approach. I have used few PHP frameworks and they uses a configuration file for selecting database driver.

Comment: Eh? Does the DSN specify that!

Comment: The only thing to do in your case is to use a `DataMapper`. If you need an explanation, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Since SQL syntax is different, (just compare SQL server vs MySQL, for example) - you cannot totally rely on PDO. You definitely need an abstraction layer for that.

Comment: Detect it, depending on what? What would be the clues that would lead to such a decision?

Answer (score 5):

Although PHP has `extension_loaded()` function, as it was noted in the comments, multiple databases support is not that easy.

Your question is a typical example of premature engineering. You don't have your CMS yet, you don't have support for even one database, but your only concern is how to detect it.